# Is LDAP DN case insensitive?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I build some feature that assumes that LDAP DN is case insensitive.

I have checked it with ActiveDirectory, Oracle and OpenLDAP and it is case insensitive.

Is it correct for all LDAPs?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

LDAP DNs and all attributes are case-insensitive by default. It is possible to define an attribute as case-sensitive in the schema, but this is rare, and it is also possible to override the default comparison rules, but again this is rare.

Comment: Can you please share one sample syntax make user DNpattern as case sensitive. We have set in properties file like below
ldap.user.dnPattern=uid={0},ou=people,dc=abcxxx,dc=eu

Answer (score 8):

I think it Depends on what you are doing.

During a bind, the DN should not be case sensitive regardless of the make up of the attributes within the DN.

[Distinguished names in Active Directory are not case sensitive.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101405&seqNum=7)

Edirectory "[Distinguished Names are not case sensitive, even if one of the naming attributes is case sensitive.](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ndslib/schm_enu/data/sdk5582.html)"

According to the LDAP protocol request for comments (RFCs), distinguished names should be **compared** case-insensitively.

Comment: Do you know if  LDAPConnection.getEntry of Unboundid is case insensitive? or it is depend on LDAP and therefore I already have the answer?

Comment: I tried AD, eDirectory and OUD with all upper and all lower case and found no differences.

Answer (score 4):

An LDAP DN is composed of several attribute value pairs (RDNs) and each one may have a different syntax. By default, all of the attributes used in naming are [DirectoryString](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/DirectoryString) and thus case-insensitive.
But one can use other attributes, such as integers, Unique Identifiers ou case-sensitive strings. As EJP said, this is rare, but it can happen.